# Perform Multiple Transformation on a DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

I am fairly new Spark Streaming

I have the streaming data containing two values x y. For example

> 1 300
>
> 2 8754
>
> 3 287

etc.

Out of the streamed data, I want to get the smallest y value, largest y value, and the mean of the x values. This needs to be output as follows (using the example above):

> 287 8754 4

I have been able to calculate these value on an individual transform/reduce but fail to do with a single transformation

Here is my current code below

```
val transformedStream = windowStream.map(line => {
  Array(line.split(" ")(0).toLong, line.split(" ")(1).toLong)

val smallest: DStream[Double]  = transformedStream.reduce((a,b) => {
  Array(0, math.min(a(1), b(1)))
}).map(u => u(1).toDouble)

val biggest  = transformedStream.reduce((a,b) => {
  Array(0, math.max(a(1), b(1)))
}).map(u => u(1).toDouble)

val mean = transformedStream.reduce((a, b) => Array( (a(0) + b(0))/2 )).
  map(u => u(0).toDouble)
```

Comment: What version of Spark is that?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski 1.6.1 I know its old, but I needed the Akka Actor integration Spark use to have.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._

windowStream.transofrm( rdd => {
  val xy = rdd.map(_.split(" ")).collect {
    case Array(x, y) => (x.toLong, y.toLong)
  }
  xy.toDF("x", "y").agg(min("y"), max("y"), mean("x"))
  .as[(Long, Long, Double)].rdd
})
```

Important:

```
transformedStream.reduce((a, b) => Array( (a(0) + b(0))/2 )
```

doesn't compute mean of `x`.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I think the only difference is `SQLContext` in place of `SparkSession`.

Comment: What about `xy.toDF`? I don't remember if it was available in pre-2.0 already.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski For `RDD[A]` and `A <: Product` since 1.3.